# Can't get Scroll to Top of browser window working

Tags: react-router, react-router-v4

So I've looked into https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/scroll-restoration and implemented in my TypeScript code as follows:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { RouteComponentProps, withRouter } from "react-router";

class ScrollToTop extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps> {
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps: RouteComponentProps) {
    if (this.props.location.pathname !== prevProps.location.pathname) {
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return this.props.children;
  }
}

export default withRouter(ScrollToTop);
```

used in my index.tsx as:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
      <ScrollToTop>
        <App />
      </ScrollToTop>
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root") as HTMLElement
);
```

However, I don't get any scrolling to top - any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had some pesky CSS that was blocking the calls:

```
overflow-y: scroll;

-ms-overflow-style: none; // IE 10+
  overflow: -moz-scrollbars-none; // Firefox

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none; // Safari and Chrome
  }
```